# SQL performance tuning with LinqPad

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, performance, entity-framework

I am DBA & Software engineer, who administers SQLServer 2016 Enterprise Database. The Application Sql is written in EntityFramework rather than Stored procedures.

Should DBAs place team's EF queries in Linqpad to performance tune in development? I learned about LinqPad last week, and amazed how it translates Linq queries into SQL. Sometimes Linq queries are unpredictable/random (MS is still working on product improvements). This way, I don't have to wait for a random query to hit SQLServer Profiler in Staging or Production. I can tune with application developers during sprint development.

Would this be a proper strategy for performance tuning? I read many sql blogs, however no one discuss LinqPad strategy. Just inquiring if this would be helpful methodology in performance tuning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mentioned your developers are using Entity Framework.  Note that, by default, LINQPad uses LINQ-to-SQL to translate LINQ expression trees into SQL queries.  Since LINQ-to-SQL and EF do not necessarily generate the same SQL output, you would want to follow the steps in the documentation for [using LINQPad with Entity Framework](https://www.linqpad.net/EntityFramework.aspx) in order to make sure that it's using the EF to create the SQL.

However, even if you configure LINQPad to use EF, there is a still a chance you could end up tuning different queries than those produced by your application.  For instance, if the Entity Data Models being used in the app are different from those selected when configuring LINQPad.  Or if your app and LINQPad are using different versions of EF, etc.

A more reliable way for your developers to view and performance test specific queries would be to configure Entity Framework to log the generated SQL somewhere - even to the "debug output" window in Visual Studio a la this MSDN blog post: [How to see the actual SQL query generated by Entity Framework](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mpeder/2014/06/16/how-to-see-the-actual-sql-query-generated-by-entity-framework/)

If they have local databases they're working against, or appropriate permissions on a dev SQL Server instance, they could also run [`sp_BlitzCache`](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit#sp_blitzcache-find-the-most-resource-intensive-queries) to track down any nasty queries being generated by Entity Framework.

LINQPad is definitely a good way to see how your LINQ expressions will be converted into SQL queries.  It helps in gaining an intuitive sense about what SQL comes out of which LINQ extension methods.  But it's probably not the *best* tool for the job if you're trying to view and tune queries generated by your application.